# How to reverse for loop in golang-revel

Tags: go, backend, revel

i'm aware that you can do for loop in `revel` like this

```
{{range $index, $element := .foo }}

{{end}}
```

but is there any way to reverse a for loop so that it can iterating from behind in revel-template, i'm looking the equivalent of this code in `golang-revel`.

```
array = [ 'a','b','c' ]
for i in reversed(array):
    print(i)
```

what i've done so far is to reversed with order by in the backend and just iterating like normal, i would like to manipulate the data so that it can be reversed in a template